# Why is my DataTable not being updated?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code that executes perfectly, but the DataTable doesn't get updated ... what am I missing / doing wrong ?!?

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.Office
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
Public txtTo As String = ""
Public txtFrom As String = ""
Public txtSubject As String = ""
Public txtBody As String = ""
Public txtAttachmentID As String = ""
Public txtAttachment As String = ""
Public MsgBoxResult As DialogResult
Public myPath As String = ""
Public dbLeague As String = ""
Public dbSession As String = "3" 
Public Sqlstring As String = ""
Public myText As String
Public newLocationRow As KickaboutEmailDataSet.FileLocationsRow

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.LeaguesTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.KickaboutEmailDataSet1.Leagues)

    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim folderBrowserDialog As New FolderBrowserDialog()

    myPath = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer

    Me.FileLocationsTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.KickaboutEmailDataSet1.FileLocations)

    If File.Exists(myPath & "\Despatch Schedule.txt") Then
        myText = ""
    Else
        myText = "to be "
    End If

    For Each Dr As DataRow In KickaboutEmailDataSet1.FileLocations.Rows
        myPath = Dr.Item(1).ToString
    Next

    folderBrowserDialog.Description = "Select Folder Where Despatch Schedule File is " & myText & "Stored"
    folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = myPath
    folderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = True

    If folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        myPath = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

> > I have written these next four lines using MSDN as my guideline, and as I've said, they execute just fine, but the Database doesn't get updated <<

```
    newLocationRow = KickaboutEmailDataSet1.FileLocations.NewFileLocationsRow()
    newLocationRow.ID = 0
    newLocationRow.DESPATCHSCHEDULE = myPath
    KickaboutEmailDataSet1.FileLocations.Rows.Add(newLocationRow)

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: First you say that the DataTable doesn't get updated and then you say that the database doesn't get updated.  They are two different things so which do you mean?  If you're expecting that adding a row to the DataTable will automatically add a record to the database then you must modify your expectations.  The DataTable is a local cache only.  To save changes to the database you must call Update on your table adapter.

Comment: I understand that the Database contains DataTables and I realise that until the data is actually written / committed to the DataTable than the Database isn't updated, but I would have thought that when MSDN is telling me How To Add A New Row To A DataTable that they would give you ALL the necessary information, but I am obviously missing something, hence my question.

Comment: No, the database does not contain DataTables.  It contains tables.  MSDN has shown you how to add a row to a DataTable and that's exactly what you have done.  If you then expect to insert a corresponding row into the corresponding table in the database then you have to save the changes from the DataTable, which is a .NET object and not part of the database, back to the database.  As you have already been told, you do that by calling Update on your data/table adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a DataAdapter instance (SqlDataAdapter if you are using Sql Server) and call Update ... maybe you already have a useable DataAdapter as you seem to be using a typed dataset ...

Comment: I am now confused as to whether I have a Typed or UnTyped dataset :-( !!! I assumed yesterday, whilst looking into this on the MSDN page, that I do indeed have a Typed dataset, but having been reading this page this morning ... http://sourcecodematrix.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/dataset-datatable-and-dataadapter-objects/ ... which seems quite straightforward, I DO have an XSD dataset in my Solution Explorer so do I have an UnTyped dataset ?!?

My solution Explorer :

KAemail
  MyProject
  app.config
  ClassDiagram1.cd
  Form1.vb
  KickaboutEmail.vb
  KickaboutEmailDataset.xsd
  Settings.vb

Comment: the typed dataset is generated from your xsd file ... you can see the generated classes if you expand your KickaboutEmailDataset.xsd node in the solution explorer

Comment: I am starting this from scratch using VS2013 Express & SqL-Server 2013 Express to see if I can understand it better. Thanks for your help, I will very likely be using the basis of the code in the new Project so I hope it comes in handy as I understand more !!!

I do think I'll have to find a Walkthrough other tham MSDN's though, they might be good if you know what you are doing, but for a Learner they are awful !!!